# linq all function with or condition

Tags: c#, linq

My string list has two strings i.e.. image formats.

```
List<string>MyStringList = new List<string>();
MyStringList.Add(".png");
MyStringList.Add(".jpg");
MyStringList.Add(".png");
MyStringList.Add(".jpg");
MyStringList.Add(".png");
MyStringList.Add(".png");
MyStringList.Add(".jpg");
MyStringList.Add(".png");
MyStringList.Add(".jpg");
MyStringList.Add(".jpg");
```

My List contain ".jpg" or ".png" . If list contain other than those two then I want to  return false.
How can perform or condition in "All" function.

Comment: `MyStringList.All(x => x == ".png" || x == ".jpg")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-6.0) combined with [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0).

Alternatively, you could use a combination of `!`, [`.Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0) and [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0).

Either way, I would suggest that you make a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) of valid formats:

```
var validFormats = new HashSet<string> { ".jpg", ".png" };
```

and use `validFormats` to check for the source list's validity.

*(An array or a list could also be used here, but as MindSwipe commented, a `HashSet` will do a faster lookup; especially if `validFormats` grows larger than the two items.)*

---

`.All()` combined with `.Contains()` checks whether `validFormats` contains *all* entries in `MyStringList`:

```
var allFormatsAreValid = MyStringList
    .All(format => validFormats.Contains(format));
```

Whereas `.Except()` and `.Any()` combined with `!` checks if there are any entries left if you exclude all entries equal to those in `validFormats`, from the entries in `MyStringList`. If there *are* any entries left, that means that `MyStringList` contains at least one entry *unequal* to the entries in `validFormats`. Hence, the use of `!`:

```
var allFormatsAreValid = !MyStringList
    .Except(validFormats)
    .Any();
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5EauAi).

Comment: `validFormats` could (and probably should) be a `HashSet` to make lookups faster (especially in cases where `validFormats` is larger than just 2 entries)

Comment: @MindSwipe Absolutely. Thank you for helping improving my answer, it's been updated accordingly.